# Is this a case for inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have Rails models `User`, `ReadingList` and `SessionReadingList`. A user has many reading lists. A `SessionReadingList` is a special type of reading list for before a user has registered, stored in the session.

In my `ReadingListsController` every action is of the form:

```
def show
  if current_user
    #load user's reading lists
  else
    #load session reading list from session
  end
end
```

I'm wondering whether I'd be better off subclassing `ReadingListsController` so I have e.g. `SessionReadingListsController` and `UserReadingListsController`. I don't know how I'd handle the routing then though.

So, is subclassing the solution? If so, do I redirect from the `ReadingListsController` depending on `current_user`? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom route matcher that uses the appropriate controller.

```
class LoggedInConstraint < Struct.new(:value)
  def matches?(request)
    request.cookies.key?("user_token") == value
  end
end

match 'reading-list' :to => "reading_list#index", :constraints => LoggedInConstraint.new(true)
match 'reading-list' :to => "session_reading_list#index", :constraints => LoggedInConstraint.new(true)
```

Comment: The problem is there's other conditional logic, for example adding a new reading list to a user is different to adding it to the session.